# Building Symbols for NDK project takes too long in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, boost, compilation, android-ndk

I am working on an Android Project which makes use of the NDK and binds the rather large Boost C++ library. Upon every startup of Android Studio, the IDE takes a rather long time of about 1 hour (more or less, on an i7 quad-core machine) during the Building Symbols stage, during which it is effectively impossible to use the IDE. I guess the bottleneck is directly related to the huge number of symbols included in Boost.

Is there a known remedy to this problem? I have not seen many complaints about this problem, but this forum post seems to ask for help for the same issue: https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/android-studio-2-2-add-cpp-files-using-t3499634

Comment: Did you try optimizing the memory for the Android Studio? Perhaps it can make things a bit faster :https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Comment: We have the same issue with our builds under Android Studio. The difference between with and without Android Studio is huge. All optimizations I've found have done little to nothing :(

Comment: @yakobom I did try that, without success.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same issue - after upgrading my Android Studio installation to 2.3.3 yesterday, opening my project now faces me with at least 30 mins of "building symbols" at which point the IDE is effectively useless.

I can build the project via gradle commands in terminal, so I have no idea why this step is mandatory in AS.

I read that this may have something to do with using the NDK build (Android.mk?) vs. CMake (CMakeLists.txt), but I have not yet been able to convert over my .mk file to test this out. This is a legacy project, and the NDK portion is still somewhat of a mystery to me :(

Comment: Right?! This is extremely annoying... I am wondering what approach the  big video game publishers have in dealing with this and similar issues. I mean, they cannot afford to work with such impediments.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  It is a comment at best.