# Android Studio grade build takes too much time for NDK project

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I am working on NDK project and using Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 3.3, SDK version 26. NDK is already integrated with this Android Studio version, so to add a new cpp file I am just updating that file in CMakeList.txt, but after that Gradle build takes more than 20 minutes or so.

I have tried many solutions suggested on the forum
[solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859572/4923905)  and 
and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978477/4923905) , but none of these are working for me.

However, there is 1 very specific query raised 6 months back just like mine 
[Building Symbols for NDK project takes too long in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41549220/4923905)
but there is still no answer on this.
Is there any solution to this problem or not .